# Why Runtime.exec() hangs when start an executable program in cmd.exe

Tags: java, window

I am building a client application to execute **.bat** files in Windows and send the results to the server. I use `FutureTask` to handle the `stdout` and `stderr` `inputstream` and get the result status.

Everything works fine except `START` command in bat. When I execute a bat to launch a  **.exe** using `START "" "D:/abc.exe"`, the `BufferedReader(inputstream)` in `FutureTask` hangs at `readLine()` until the exe closed.

Here is my code:

```
String path = "D:/xxxx.bat";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe", "/c", path);
InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
InputStream er = p.getErrorStream();

StreamOut out = new StreamOut(in, "out");
FutureTask<boolean> outResult = new FutureTask<>(out);
new Thread(outResult).start();
StreamError error = new StreamError(er, "error");
FutureTask<boolean> errResult = new FutureTask<>(error);
new Thread(errResult).start();

Boolean success = outResult.get(); // stuck here
Boolean error = errResult.get(); // and here
```

and the StreamOut class:

```
@Override
public Boolean call() {
    boolean success = true;
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStream(in));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            ....
            sendLine(line);
            ....
        }
    return success;
}
```

Here is the xxxx.bat:

```
start "" "D:/abc.exe"
```

How can I fix this? thx

Comment: .bat and .exe are not same, though they seems to be same at the surface. BAT (short for "batch") file is a plain text file that contains a series of Windows commands. An .EXE (short for "executable") file is a binary file that contains much more complex executable binary code.

Comment: Just added my code